# clamsmtpd won't start with the user specified in clamsmtpd.conf

Tags: debian, smtp, clamav

Since I upgraded my server from Debian Stretch to Debian Buster, `clamsmtpd` is always running under the `clamsmtp` user althoug I specified to run under the `clamav` user in `/etc/clamsmtpd.conf` file. Here is the content of that file:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                        SAMPLE CLAMSMTPD CONFIG FILE
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# - Comments are a line that starts with a #
# - All the options are found below with their defaults commented out


# The address to send scanned mail to.
# This option is required unless TransparentProxy is enabled
OutAddress: 10025

# The maximum number of connection allowed at once.
# Be sure that clamd can also handle this many connections
#MaxConnections: 64

# Amount of time (in seconds) to wait on network IO
#TimeOut: 180

# Address to listen on (defaults to all local addresses on port 10025)
Listen: 127.0.0.1:10026

# The address clamd is listening on
ClamAddress: /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl

# A header to add to all scanned email
Header: X-AV-Checked: ClamAV using ClamSMTP

# Directory for temporary files
TempDirectory: /var/spool/clamsmtp

# PidFile: location of PID file
PidFile: /var/run/clamsmtp/clamsmtpd.pid

# Whether or not to bounce email (default is to silently drop)
#Bounce: off

# Whether or not to keep virus files
#Quarantine: off

# Enable transparent proxy support
#TransparentProxy: off

# User to run as
#User: clamsmtp
User: clamav

# Virus actions: There's an option to run a script every time a
# virus is found. Read the man page for clamsmtpd.conf for details.
```

After restarting the service with `service clamsmtp restart` and issuing the command `ps -eaf`, I can see `/usr/sbin/clamsmtpd` running under the `clamsmtp` user. Any clue what could prevent the daemon from using the value specified in its configuration file?

Comment: Do both users exist? `getent passwd clamav;getent passwd clamsmtp`

Comment: @waltinator Yes, both users exist. But I found the answer to my question. See my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since, I posted this question, I discovered this file `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/clamsmtp.service` which contains parameters to start the clamsmtp service:

```
[Unit]
Description=virus-scanning SMTP proxy clamsmtp
Documentation=man:clamsmtpd(8)
After=network.target local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=clamsmtp
Group=clamsmtp
RuntimeDirectory=clamsmtp
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/clamsmtpd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Notice the User parameter which specifies under which user to run this service. I switched that line to `User=clamav`, restarted the service and `clamsmtpd` is now running under the `clamav` user.

I also discovered why the `User` parameter specified in `/etc/clamsmtpd.conf` was not taken into account. In the [clamsmtpd.conf man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/clamsmtp/clamsmtpd.conf.5.en.html), it says the following concerning the `User` parameter:

> User: The user to run as. If this option is specified then clamsmtpd(8)
> must be started as root. It will then drop root privileges and run as
> the specified user. The user can either be a name or a numerical user
> id.

Since, the service was not started as root, the switch to the specified user was not done.